# Como forçar o método '.on("input")' via script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suponto o meu método:

```
$(document).on("input", "#textbox", function(){
    alert("oi");
});
```

Qual script que posso forçar a chamada do alert("oi") ?

Tentei varios e nada:

```
$("input#textbox").val("1");
$("#textbox").val("1").on("input");
$("#textbox").input("1");
$("#textbox").input("1").change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyqu4s92/

Comportamento esperado:

Ao digitar um caractere no campo quantidade, deve ser chamada uma funcao que calculara os campos valor e quantidade pra jogar no campo total. Ao iniciar a página essa funcao tem que ser chamada tambem. O caso real é esse: um campo com valor, outro com quantidade e outro com o total vazio. Ao abrir a página o campo quantidade estará por padrão valor 1, o campo valor vai variar e o total sera calculado em cima desses dois valores.

Comment: não consegui entender bem o que você quis dizer porém no fiddle esta funcionando no change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você chegou perto no fiddle:

```
$("#textbox").trigger("input");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyqu4s92/1/

Comment: Estranho. No meu caso real não funciona direto. Funciona apenas quando clico com o mouse no input, ai ele chama a função. Não tenho nenhuma função de click no meu js.

Comment: Em que browser? No meu chrome funciona.

Comment: Esquece. Foi uma burrice minha aqui. Funcionou legal, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Se o objetivo é simplesmente chamar a função, por que não dar um nome a ela e chamá-la diretamente?

```
function callback(){
    alert("oi");
}
$(document).on("input", "#textbox", callback);
callback();
```

Comment: Só pra economizar código mesmo.